# Fatal error: Class 'CWebApplication' not found in ...YiiRoot/framework/YiiBase.php on line 125

Tags: php, web-applications, yii

I couldn't access this file on the server. I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'CWebApplication' not found in DOMAIN/YiiRoot/framework/YiiBase.php on line 125
```

`framework/YiiBase.php`

```
123 public static function createApplication($class,$config=null)
124 {
125  return new $class($config);
126 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've setup the yii application correctly.

If you're using `yii1` then check if `protected/config/main.php` exists in your application, as this is being called in `index.php` file:

```
<?php

$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php'; //make sure this exists

defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run(); //this is the reason for your error
```

I guess the last line `Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();` is the reason for your error as it cannot find `main.php` file in `config/`